# How can I use webform to "assign to another client" for civicase

Tags: civicase

I am trying to provide a webform that can be used to assign a case (and lots of relationships) to another client. I don't seem to be able to get this to replicate the outcome of doing this via the civicase UI. Currently via webform it does create a new Case for the new client, but it does not create/record Activities such as "Case 69 reassigned client from xxx to yyy. New Case ID is 111." nor copy over Activities that were on the original Case.

I have tried by putting the original case id in the url.

Is there something I am missing that would make this work?